# libgdx texture from code on mesh of model

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, libgdx

I want to render a few 3D models, to be concrete cards (but should have 3 dimensions) with different values on the front-side.

To accomplish this I thought it would be a good idea to create a model which represents the dimensions and form of a card, if possible already supply a default-texture for the card and add card-specific values like a number different for every rendered model.

I'm already able to load the model with default-texture and render to screen, ***but I don't have any clue how to add the dynamic texture to the front-side of the model***.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a TextureAttribute per each card type, then set it into the material of each model instance:

```
TextureAttribute textureAttribute1 = new TextureAttribute(TextureAttribute.Diffuse, yourtexture);

//

material = modelinstance.materials.get(0);
material.set(textureAttribute1);`
```

Comment: This way I was able to set a complete different texture... I can work with this, but my original goal was to change only one side of the model... Do you have any clue for me how this can be accomplished?
I think it could be possible to split the materials... now it's just  a single one... Is there a way in code or only via changing the model?

Comment: Ok, tried it with changing the model, but it changed nothing... Now the second material is the only one... Maybe it's not supported now...

Comment: Im not sure about that, the 3d api is relatively new and I haven't had the time to look into it u.u

Comment: Hey do you know how to repeat that texture over the model? I have the similar problem, your answer works, but I need that texture also repeated. Help?

Answer (score 0):

You have probably worked this out ages ago, but to put a texture on the front side of the model depends on the uvs you create in your modelling sofware. So if you split the front side uvs on a separate island from your side uvs then that will be one of your numbers. For instance if have 4 uv islands your texture would go from 0 to 3. So your front side would be one of these numbers. The model would have to be unwrapped correctly for this to work though.

Also you have to add a multi/sub texture and number each one different. Then and only then will you see a different texture on each side. Only thing I haven't managed to do is to scale the texture correctly.